# selecting an entire row based on a variable excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select an entire row in a different sheet and then copy the row to the sheet I am currently in with a macro. The code works fine if the Rows() sub is passed integers hardcoded but when I put a variable I get the "Select method of Range class failed" error. here is the code I have:

```
Sheets("BOM").Select
Rows(copyFromRow & ":" & copyFromRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Proposal").Select
Rows(copyToRow & ":" & copyToRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
copyToRow = copyToRow + 1
Rows(copyToRow & ":" & copyToRow).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

if instead i used :

```
Rows("52:52").Select
Selection.Copy
```

it works fine, but when the variable is there, the error occurs.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the value of `copyFromRow` in debugging mode? Is it 52? Also if `copyFromRow` is a number, you can simply use `Rows(copyFromRow)`.

Comment: yes it is the correct value, and i tried both ways, neither works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested the code at the bottom and it prints `16384` twice (I'm on Excel 2010) and the first row gets selected. Your problem seems to be somewhere else.

Have you tried to get rid of the selects:

```
Sheets("BOM").Rows(copyFromRow).Copy
With Sheets("Proposal")
    .Paste Destination:=.Rows(copyToRow)
    copyToRow = copyToRow + 1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Rows(copyToRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With
```

---

Test code to get convinced that the problem does not seem to be what you think it is.

```
Sub test()

  Dim r
  Dim i As Long

  i = 1

  r = Rows(i & ":" & i)
  Debug.Print UBound(r, 2)
  r = Rows(i)
  Debug.Print UBound(r, 2)
  Rows(i).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem for me by addressing also the worksheet first:

```
ws.rows(x & ":" & y).Select
```

without the reference to the worksheet (ws) I got an error.

Answer (score 2):

Saw this answer on another site and it works for me as well!

> Posted by Shawn on October 14, 2001 1:24 PM
>
> `var1 = 1`
>
> `var2 = 5`
>
> `Rows(var1 & ":" & var2).Select`
>
> That worked for me, looks like you just have to keep the variables outside the quotes and add the and statement (&)
>
> -Shawn

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the quotes around the colon and &, i.e. rows(variable & ":" & variable).select

Adapt this:

```
Rows(x & ":" & y).select
```

where x and y are your variables.

Some other examples that may help you understand

```
Rows(x & ":" & x).select
```

Or

```
Rows((x+1) & ":" (x*3)).select
```

Or

```
Rows((x+2) & ":" & (y-3)).select
```

Hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes. VBA is translating

```
Rows(copyToRow & ":" & copyToRow).Select`
```

into

```
 Rows(52:52).Select
```

Try changing

```
Rows(""" & copyToRow & ":" & copyToRow & """).Select
```

Comment: No, `copyToRow & ":" & copyToRow` is already a string. What you propose will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to make sure the space between the variables and '&' sign.
Check the image. (Red one showing invalid commands)

[image: Error]

The correct solution is

```
Dim copyToRow: copyToRow = 5      
Rows(copyToRow & ":" & copyToRow).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mycell = ActiveCell
r = mycell.Row
c = mycell.Column
Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r + 100, c)).Select
```